# How To Filter Out List of Word from ElasticSearch Query Result?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```java
context.analyzer("email_indexing_exact")
                .custom()
                .tokenizer("uax_url_email");
```

```java
        SearchSession searchSession = Search.session(entityManager);
        String[] fieldsArray = {"displayName", "email"};
        String[] filterEmailArray = filterEmail.split(",");

        var query = searchSession.search(User.class)
                .extension(ElasticsearchExtension.get())
                .select(ElasticsearchSearchProjectionFactory::source)
                .where(f -> f.bool()
                        .must(f.match().fields(fieldsArray).matching(word).analyzer("autocomplete_search"))
                        .mustNot(f.match().field("email").matching(filterEmailArray[0]).analyzer("email_indexing_exact"))
                )
                .sort(f -> f.score().desc());
```

As you can see I only can filter out the 0th index of the array. How to filter out all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TermsSetContext` query instead of the `MatchContext`.

Replace this line:

```
.mustNot(f.match().field("email").matching(filterEmailArray[0]).analyzer("email_indexing_exact"))
```

with the next one:

```
.mustNot(f.termsSet().field("email").terms(filterEmailArray).analyzer("email_indexing_exact"))
```

Note: the `termsSet` query is only available in Elasticsearch 7.0 and later.

**Update**
for your 6.1.8. version try next:

```
.mustNot(f.terms().field("email").matching(Arrays.asList(filterEmailArray)).analyzer("email_indexing_exact"))
```

Note: the `terms` query has limitations, such as a limit of 65,536 terms.

Comment: I have this dependency  ```<dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch</artifactId><version>6.1.8.Final</version></dependency> ``` 

and get this error ```Cannot resolve method 'termsSet' in 'ElasticsearchSearchPredicateFactory'``` Could you please tell me which version have this?

Comment: @UmutEmreÖnder, the `termsSet` query is only available in Elasticsearch 7.0 and later

Comment: Thanks, I did a little bit additional update and its working. ```.mustNot(f.terms().field("email").matchingAny(List.of(filterEmailArray)))```

Comment: @UmutEmreÖnder, nice move